# How do i create an Address Block variable

Tags: address

Looking to create and address block from several custom fields. Example.... 4 separate custom variables.

```
Address1: 100 Grant Street
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60601
```

Would like them displayed as:

```
100 Grant Street
Chicago, IL 60601
```

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Try a text formula field

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom formula field of type text.  For example, (assuming that your custom field names match the labels you showed in the question):

```
Address1__c + BR() + City__c + IF(City__c!=null, ',', '') + ' ' + State__c + ' ' + Zip__c
```

The `IF(City__c!=null, ',', '')` part lets you skip the comma after city if the city value was null.

**edit:** updated formula to add newline using the BR() function after address1, which I initially overlooked.  Note that some parts of the UI may omit the newline.